# Printer ignoring paper color changes

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I am using a brother label printer which depending on the paper set to use It may or may not be able to print in color (paper 62mm X 100mm let you use color but 29mm X 90mm only allows monochrome).

so, in order to save time and effort to the user I want to configure those properties at runtime by code (Paper Size, Color/monochrome).

I have a checkbox for selecting monochrome or color and the paper size I get it from a FastReport.

The main problem is that when I try to change those properties the paper size is indeed modified but the color property just seems to be ignored or something because it doesn’t change at all.

I check this by showing a PrinterSetupDialog before and after running the following code:

```
 procedure TEtiquetas.pruebas2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Device, Driver, Port: array[0..80] of Char;
DevMode: THandle;
pDevmode: PDeviceMode;
begin
  ReportePrueba.PrintOptions.Clear;
 {Get printer device name etc.}
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DevMode);
  {force reload of DEVMODE}
  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, 0);
  {get DEVMODE handle}
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DevMode);
  if Devmode <> 0 then
  begin
    {lock it to get pointer to DEVMODE record}
    pDevMode := GlobalLock(Devmode);
    if pDevmode <> nil then
    try
      with pDevmode^ do
      begin
      ShowMessage('Color: '+dmColor.ToString);// to check the color configured
        if monocromo.Checked then
        begin
          dmColor:= DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME;
          dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_COLOR;
        end
        else
        begin
          dmColor:= DMCOLOR_COLOR;
          dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_COLOR;
        end;
        {tell printer driver that dmPapersize field contains data it needs to inspect}
        dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_COLOR;
        {modify paper size}
        dmPapersize := TfrxReportPage(ReportePrueba.FindObject('Page1')).PaperSize; //FastReport
        ShowMessage('Color: '+dmColor.ToString);//checking the color again and it does change
      end;

      Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DevMode);
    finally
     PrinterSetup.Execute;
    {unlock DEVMODE handle}
    GlobalUnlock(Devmode);
    ReportePrueba.PrintOptions.Printer:= Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex];// setting the report's printer
    end;
  end;

end;
```

when I show the PrinterSetupDialog before running the procedure above, both paper size and color are not the ones I need (lets say paper: 62 X 100, Color: red/black)

and after I run the procedure I get the right paper, so it does modify the printer but the color is completely ignored (lets say paper: 29 X 90, Color: red/black) in this case I wanted the color to change to monochrome but it just doesn't.

I have no clue on how to change the printer's properties by code, if you have any advice I'll appreciate it a lot.

I use Delphi Rio VCL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706108/reading-and-writting-devmode-dmcolor
I think I am having the same problem than this post, but I have no clue on how to achieve what he did. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For your changes to the `dmColor` field to take effect, you need to set the `DM_COLOR` bit of `dmFields` in addition to the `DM_PAPERSIZE` bit:

```
dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_COLOR
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_devicemodea)

> dmFields
>
> Specifies whether certain members of the DEVMODE structure have been initialized. If a member is initialized, its corresponding bit is set, otherwise the bit is clear. A driver supports only those DEVMODE members that are appropriate for the printer or display technology.

Your printer driver did not consider your changes to the `dmColor` field, since you did not set the corresponding `dmFields` bit (`DM_COLOR`).

---

Edit, addition of code to inspect the DEVMODE structure:

You can use the following code (**NOTE! incomplete**, but sufficient for the current discussion):

```
// insert into your code into the `try` block after `if pDevmode <> nil then`
....
    if pDevmode <> nil then
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Devmode read');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');

      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmSpecVersion:          '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmSpecVersion));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmDriverVersion:        '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmDriverVersion));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmSize, public:         '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmSize));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmDriverExtra, private: '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmDriverExtra));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmOrientation:          '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmOrientation));
      ...
      Memo1.Lines.Add('dmColor:                '+IntToStr(pDevMode.dmColor));
```

Comment: Hello @Tom Brunberg, I tried your suggestion but the printer still didn’t change the color, I edited the code I used in my question and added what you suggested, any ideas why it won't work even if I added `dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_COLOR` ? thanks for answering.

Comment: Perhaps your printer uses its own proprietary private structure after the public DEVMODE structure. But then you are on the mercy of your printers manufacturer, whether they want to give that specification to you. You can chek whether such a private part exists by reading the `dmDriverExtra` in the `DEWMODEW` structure. It indicates the size of such a private part. Note though that even if the private part exists, it doesn't mean that the printer wouldn't use the public part for most settings. Is the value of `dmColor` different, after you change the color setting with the printersetup dialog?

Comment: Yes, it is different, If I showmessage it before and after the printersetup it changes but I get 0, isn't it supposed to be only 1 or 2 for monochrome and color? and I get and access violation on SetPrinter because of that 0 I think

Comment: how do I read the `dmDriverExtra` and work with the `DEWMODEW` ?

Comment: I added some code to read the `dmDriverExtra` field, I had some code that shows the values in a memo. Modify as you see fit. You are right about `dmColor`values, should be either `DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME` (1) or `DMCOLOR_COLOR` (2). So, please say again, which value you get (with what setting, in setup dialog) A zero in the field can not cause an AV.

Comment: this are the values I get from your code: 
`Devmode read

dmSpecVersion:          1025
dmDriverVersion:        1280
dmSize, public:         220
dmDriverExtra, private: 320
dmOrientation:          2
dmColor:                1`

and I get a 0 from selecting either monochrome or color on the printer setup

Comment: Huh? If you get `dmColor = 0` which ever setting you select in the setup dialog, what changes the value to `dmColor: 1`

Comment: I change those by code, in an if, setting it to DMCOLOR_COLOR or DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME, but when I show the setup and select one it changes to 0 and crashes on printer.setprinter because of that. do you want me to update my code so that you can see it with the additions you showed me?

Comment: Ah, are you using the printers own setup dialog at the same time that you have e.g. stopped on a line in your code. You can not do that, and it would explain the AV, because the handle would become invalid . What I have meant, is that you change the color setting, with the printers setup dialog and then you start your code and read. Then change again with the dialog and then read with code.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll change that and let you know.

Comment: So, I show on a button click a PrinterSetupDialog and then change the color to monochrome, then in other button click I execute the code to fill the memo and I get `dmColor: 1` and when I click the button for the PrinterSetup again monochrome is not selected, red/black color is selected

Comment: Ok, then one simple test more. Do the same test again but first prevent your code from writing anything to the printer, by outcommenting the line `Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DevMode);`. What happens with the two setups from the dialog and the `dmColor` values

Comment: by commenting that line and then changing the color in the setup and the running the procedure that fills the memo, dmColor is still 1 but when I show again the setup red/black color is selected.

Comment: as a matter of fact, if I change the papersize on the setup and the run the procedure to fill the memo, the papersize doesn’t change either. it displays the same no matter what I choose, but if I change it on the procedure by code it does change and when I run the setup the selected size appears correctly.

Comment: I think I'm running out of ideas, and have to drop the issue for now. But what is the brand and model of your printer, if I try to find some information.

Comment: it is a Brother QL-800 Label Printer. and don't worry Tom, I appreciate your efforts, if you find anything please do let me know but if you don't that’s okay, this problem has been so tricky.